# add search icon to the left of toolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to achieve rtl toolbar and for that I use the tricky way . 
for that i inflate this menu into the toolbar . but now i want add search icon in left of the toolbar . also i set the `getSupportActionbar.setTitle("");`for removing title .

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="My Title"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title=""
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />

</menu>
```

this is the toolbar screenshot from my toolbar and i mark the place for the search icon exactly .

[image]

Comment: Which Activity u are extending ? ActionBarActivity or only Activity?

Comment: hi . i use AppcompatActivity .

Comment: Read about [action views](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/appbar/action-views.html)

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: i want to know how can i put search icon left side of toolbar .

Comment: Have you tried to put the `android:supportsRtl="true"` attribute in your AndroidManifest file and set your layout direction in the `onCreate` method?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your menu file.hope this will work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Search / will display always -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
          android:title="search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. She wants to know how to align the search to the right

Answer (score 0):

From Android API Level 17+ it supports RTL natively. To force your entire layout to be RTL including the ActionBar do the following.

Edit your AndroidManifest.xml and add android:supportsRtl="true" to your `<application>` tag and then add the following line to the top of your Activities' onCreate() method forceRTLIfSupported(); and then insert the follow function into your Activity.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
private void forceRTLIfSupported()
{
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
        getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    }
}
```

Of course that's only helpful for debugging. Use **View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LOCALE** for production builds so your layout is only changed when the user chosen system location/language aka locale supports RTL.

Hope that helps.